# SendKey command working with vbs but not C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am trying to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> from a windows form button (C#) to rotate my screen. It is an intel hotkey.
When I press the button nothing is happening, but if I use almost the same command in a vbs file it works.

This is the c# code which does not work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("^%{LEFT}");
}
```

vb script which does work:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.SendKeys "^%{LEFT}"
```

I'm very new to all this so maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Try to use `SendKeys.SendWait()`

Comment: Same result. I just noticed that send and sendwait both work on my windows 8 pc, but not on the xp machine I need it for.

Comment: The keystroke is effective only on hardware that actually supports this. Moreover, SendKeys sends the keystroke to [the current application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while the script sends it to your desktop

Comment: Both pc's are running intel graphics which have the hkcmd.exe background process looking out for those keypresses. The strange thing is why does the c# method I used above work on win8 but not xp

Answer (score 1):

maybe is a parenthesis issue:

```
SendKeys.Send("^(%{LEFT})");
```

you can find more details in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) where is stated that:

> To specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held
>   down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those
>   keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E and C are pressed, use "+(EC)". To specify to hold down SHIFT while
>   E is pressed, followed by C without SHIFT, use "+EC".

not sure about the behaviour of VBS: i would expect the very same behavior of C# because the [VBS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) for SendKeys say so...